# Do you consider the size of the data type when you creating variables?

Tags: java, variables, types, size

When we create a variable, do we need to think about the size of the data type?
For example `int myNum = 125;` or `byte myNum = 125;`
I asked this question to know your ideas according to your practical experiences. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I think about the purpose of the variable, and the type of operations I'll need to be able to perform. The moment the size of the variable becomes your first concern, it's type to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: In most cases the size of a data type is fairly irrelevant and thus you'd use what makes the most sense. This could mean that there's just 1 or 2 types of numbers, e.g. the JSON specification just hat the "number" type. However, there also may be cases where the size of a data type (or yet better the data itself) may be relevant, e.g. when dealing with hardware or network restrictions like embedded systems, network latency or pricing based data volumes. Those cases, however, should be quite rare and thus the general rule of thumb is: think of other properties first., e.g. devoper productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **int** unless you have good reason to do otherwise.  This is the "natural" size for the implementation.

- **long** if values can reasonably be expected to exceed the range of plain integers.
- **short** or **byte** if you're matching some external requirements (protocol structures, etc) or just possibly if you're expected a large (hundreds of thousands?) quantity of them.

As an example of the consideration I might give: let's say I need to generate an integer id for something. If I figure I might generate them once a millisecond on average, then using **int** I'm going to run out after about 27 days of uptime, which feels sort of low, so **long** seems a better choice.